# difference between pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame and pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame and their conversion

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I could not find any detailed documentation on this point, so what is the difference between a `pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame` and `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame`, and where to find the documentation of their methods?

Also how to cast, or convert one into the other and vice versa? Is it always seamless to convert them or some data types are not recognised?

Comment: [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/index.html) is the doc for pyspark-pandas (AKA pandas API on pyspark) which generates (or uses) the `pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame`. You can look through the [spark doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/dataframe.html) for its native dataframe methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/index.html) is the doc for pyspark-pandas (AKA pandas API on pyspark) which generates (or uses) the [`pyspark.pandas.DataFrame`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.html#pyspark-pandas-dataframe). You can look through the [spark doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/dataframe.html) for its native dataframe methods.

Both of them have conversion methods that can be used to convert one to other.

- converting pyspark dataframe to pyspark-pandas dataframe can be done using [`to_pandas_on_spark`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.to_pandas_on_spark.html#pyspark-sql-dataframe-to-pandas-on-spark)
- converting pyspark-pandas dataframe to pyspark dataframe can be done using [`to_spark`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.to_spark.html#pyspark-pandas-dataframe-to-spark)