# What is the difference between pyspark.pandas to pandas?

Tags: pandas, pyspark

Starting to use PySpark on Databricks, and I see I can import `pyspark.pandas` alongside `pandas`. What is the different?
I assume it's not like `koalas`, right?

Comment: see [Pandas API on Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/index.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73694960/8279585). pyspark pandas lets you write pandas codes on spark dataframes

Answer (score 3):

PySpark is an interface for Apache Spark in Python. It allows you to write Spark applications using Python and provides the PySpark shell to analyze data in a distributed environment.
`Pyspark.pandas` is an API that allows you to use pandas functions and operations on "spark data frames".

Koalas is another library developed by Databricks that allows running pandas-like operations on spark data.

This blog show some differences between pyspark.pandas and pyspark:
https://towardsdatascience.com/run-pandas-as-fast-as-spark-f5eefe780c45

Pyspark.pandas documentation is of course a reference:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/index.html

Answer (score 2):

[pyspark.pandas](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/frame.html) is an alternative to pandas, with the **same api** than pandas.
This means you can work with pyspark exactly the same as you work with pandas

for example, to create a dataframe, you use `.DataFrame` same as with pandas, and use `.iloc` or `.drop_duplicates` :

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
df = ps.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b':[3, 4]})
df.sort_valyes('b')

df1 = ps.read_csv('data.csv') 
df1.sort_values(by="date")
```

also, you can convert the pyspark dataframe to pandas dataframe:

```
df.to_pandas() #return pandas dataframe
```