# Nested struct type not supported pyspark error

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I am attempting to apply a function to a pyspark DataFrame and save the API response to a new column and then parse using `json_normalize`. This works fine in pandas, however, I run into an exception with `pyspark`.

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
import pandas as pd
import requests


def get_vals(row):

    # make api call
    return row['A'] * row['B']
 

# Create a pandas DataFrame
pdf = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})


# apply function - get api responses
pdf['api_response'] = pdf.apply(lambda row: get_vals(row), axis=1)
pdf.sample(5)

# Unpack JSON API Response
try:
   dff = pd.json_normalize(pdf['api_response'].str['location'])
except TypeError as e:
   print(f"Error: {e}")
   print(f"Problematic data: {data['data']}")


# To pySpark DataFrame
psdf = ps.DataFrame(df)
psdf.head(5)
```

Expected output is a `json` normalized DataFrame. When I attempt to apply the function over a `pyspark` DataFrame, it throws an exception:

```
psdf['api_response'] = psdf.apply(lambda row: get_vals(row), axis=1)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-4372401754138893>:2
      1 
----> 2 psdf['api_response'] = psdf.apply(lambda row: get_vals(row), axis=1)

TypeError: Nested StructType not supported in conversion from Arrow: struct<data: struct<geographies:
```

Comment: This code doesn't seem like something what would run, even if we skip the `....` part, `df` just appears from thin air.

Comment: @tevemadar fixed the typo and it calls an external api, so I have update the api call function as well.

Comment: The exception has both `lambda row: get_ll_scores(row)` and `lambda row: get_vals(row)`.  Which is it?

Comment: @JohnGordon `get_vals(row)`

Comment: Does the `apply` in pyspark.pandas` work the same as `apply` in pandas? I would check this. Related: [stackoverflow: pyspark.pandas vs. pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73788459/what-is-the-difference-between-pyspark-pandas-to-pandas)